# How can get length on checked checkbox array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I want to use jQuery to get the length of a checkbox array such as the following:

```
<li><input name="skills['11111']" class="skills" value="1" type="checkbox" /></li>
<li><input name="skills['22222']" class="skills" value="2" type="checkbox" /></li>
<li><input name="skills['33333']" class="skills" value="3" type="checkbox" /></li>
<li><input name="skills['44444444']" class="skills" value="4" type="checkbox" /></li>
```

`<li><input name="test['999999999']" class="tesst" value="4" type="checkbox" /></li>`

Also, I have some field input checkbox diffirent name and I only want to get checkbox `name= skills`

In this case, the length will be 4.  How can I do this?

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length`

Comment: sorry, I have some field input checkbox but I only want to get checkbox name= skills.

Comment: Learn basic query selectors...

Comment: This is not a real question. And Stackoverflow is no free code writing service. Consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So having those 5+ checkboxes you want to:

> get only those whos `name` attribute starts-with `skills=[`

```js
var $skills = $(":checkbox[name^='skills[']");
var totSkills = $skills.length;

console.log("There are %d skills checkboxes",  totSkills);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input name="skills['11111']" class="skills" value="1" type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input name="skills['22222']" class="skills" value="2" type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input name="skills['33333']" class="skills" value="3" type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input name="skills['44444444']" class="skills" value="4" type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input name="test['999999999']" class="tesst" value="4" type="checkbox" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: great. Thank you so much